# Calculate running total for net shortage with recursive adjustment and capped surplus

Tags: sql, sql-server, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to calculate the net shortage on a series of values with the following conditions (shaped into this hypothetical):

- There is a static run day quota for any given set (production cycle) of data, e.g. 30
- There is a production yield for any given day
- Depending on the yield, there could be a shortage or a surplus for the day
- Shortage accumulates through the production cycle and is offset by surplus but only up to zero
- Surplus cannot be applied if there is no shortage, i.e. surplus cannot be "banked" for future shortage

Representation of a production run:

| Date | Quota | Yield | Shortage | Surplus | NetShort |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2000 | 30 | 30 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 01-05-2000 | 30 | 25 | -5 | 0 | -5 |
| 01-06-2000 | 30 | 30 | 0 | 0 | -5 |
| 01-09-2000 | 30 | 28 | -2 | 0 | -7 |
| 01-15-2000 | 30 | 34 | 0 | 4 | -3 |
| 01-17-2000 | 30 | 30 | 0 | 0 | -3 |
| 01-19-2000 | 30 | 29 | -1 | 0 | -4 |
| 01-20-2000 | 30 | 37 | 0 | 7 | 0 |
| 01-21-2000 | 30 | 32 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 01-24-2000 | 30 | 27 | -3 | 0 | -3 |
| 01-25-2000 | 30 | 30 | 0 | 0 | -3 |

For each day I need to know if there was a shortage or surplus and the net shortage for the entire run. I don't need to know the daily net but provided to illustrate how it accumulates. Based on the data set, the net shortage for the run is -3.

I've tried doing the calculation in a query using SUM() OVER(ORDER BY Date) but always get hung up because applying the surplus depends on the net shortage and the net shortage depends on the surplus. What I ended up doing was to query the above data sans the NetShortage, then loop through the result on the C# side using conditional logic to modify an accumulator. This works fine but I'm really curious if there is a way to do this directly in SQL (query, not just the equivalent loop in a stored procedure)

I've tried doing the calculation in a query using SUM() OVER(ORDER BY Date) but always get hung up because applying the surplus depends on the net shortage and the net shortage depends on the surplus. What I ended up doing was to query the above data sans the NetShortage column, then loop through the result on the C# side using conditional logic to modify an accumulator. This works fine but I'm really curious if there **is a way to do this directly in SQL** (query, not just the equivalent loop in a stored procedure).

Comment: What's the database? Easy in PostgreSQL.

Comment: I have tried this, I have tried that, but we don't see a single query ...

Comment: @TheImpaler MS SQL Server. How would you do it in PostgresSQL?

Comment: Which you your sample data and which is your desired data? Is your desired the last 3 columns?

Comment: @DaleK Sample data would be the larger set of all production cycle data. The desired data would be the subset (for January) as above, specifically the net shortage at the end of the cycle (-3). I can get everything from above in a query except for the last column; I have to process the set programmatically to calculate that.

Comment: How do you come up with your last 4 columns?  What is your logic?

Comment: @Eric Yield is the real-world value, e.g. on Jan. 5, the factory produced 25 widgets. Shortage is the amount yield is below quota or surplus is the amount yield is above quota. The last column is what I haven't been able to do directly in the query...

Comment: Sorry, the last 4 rows, not columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a recursive CTE to compute these values. You can do:

```sql
with
x as (
  select t.*,
    least(yield - quota, 0) as shortage,
    greatest(yield - quota, 0) as surplus,
    row_number() over(order by date) as rn
  from t
),
n as (
  select x.*, least(shortage + surplus, 0) as netshort from x where rn = 1
 union all
  select x.*, least(n.netshort + x.shortage + x.surplus, 0)
  from n
  join x on x.rn = n.rn + 1
)  
select * from n;
```

Result:

```
 Date        Quota  Yield  shortage  surplus  rn  netshort 
 ----------- ------ ------ --------- -------- --- -------- 
 2000-01-01  30     30     0         0        1    0        
 2000-01-05  30     25     -5        0        2   -5       
 2000-01-06  30     30     0         0        3   -5       
 2000-01-09  30     28     -2        0        4   -7       
 2000-01-15  30     34     0         4        5   -3       
 2000-01-17  30     30     0         0        6   -3       
 2000-01-19  30     29     -1        0        7   -4       
 2000-01-20  30     37     0         7        8    0        
 2000-01-21  30     32     0         2        9    0        
 2000-01-24  30     27     -3        0        10  -3       
 2000-01-25  30     30     0         0        11  -3
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pOi4WZLd).

**Note**: Consider that by default SQL Server ships with a low limit in recursive iterations (*maxrecursion* = 100?). If that's the case, you'll need to add an extra SQL clause to increase the number of iterations as needed.

Comment: Oh yes, so very nice. I was close to something like this many times; I knew there was recursion needed somewhere in there, but I just wasn't able to get my head around it. Then it got to the point where I needed to give up on functional _and_ elegant and just get it done and move on. Thank you!

Comment: As I'm trying to integrate this into my actual system, I noticed that it can be simplified a little bit based on the rules. In the recursive CTE, where rn = 1, since this is the first day and surplus can only be applied when there is a shortage:
`select x.*, shortage as netshort from x where rn = 1`

Comment: @jdcook72 Yes, if that's a rule you are sure about, then you can simplify it.

Answer (score 0):

[Quirky Update](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/solving-the-running-total-and-ordinal-rank-problems-rewritten)

```
CREATE TABLE #t
(
    [Date] date NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ,Quota int NOT NULL
    ,Yield int NOT NULL
    ,Shortage int NULL
    ,Surplus int NULL
    ,NetShort int NULL
);
INSERT INTO #t ([Date], Quota, Yield)
VALUES ('2000-01-01', 30, 30)
    ,('2000-01-05', 30, 25)
    ,('2000-01-06', 30, 30)
    ,('2000-01-09', 30, 28)
    ,('2000-01-15', 30, 34)
    ,('2000-01-17', 30, 30)
    ,('2000-01-19', 30, 29)
    ,('2000-01-20', 30, 37)
    ,('2000-01-21', 30, 32)
    ,('2000-01-24', 30, 27)
    ,('2000-01-25', 30, 30);

DECLARE @check int
    ,@Anchor date
    ,@NetShort int = 0;

UPDATE T
SET Shortage = CASE WHEN Yield < Quota THEN Yield - Quota ELSE 0 END
    ,Surplus = CASE WHEN Yield > Quota THEN Yield - Quota ELSE 0 END
    ,@NetShort = CASE
                    WHEN @NetShort + Yield - Quota < 0
                    THEN @NetShort + Yield - Quota
                    ELSE 0
                END
    ,NetShort = @NetShort
    ,@check = CASE WHEN [Date] > ISNULL(@Anchor, '1900') THEN 1 ELSE 1/0 END
    ,@Anchor = [Date]
FROM #t T WITH (TABLOCKX)
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);

SELECT [Date], Quota, Yield, Shortage, Surplus, NetShort
FROM #t
ORDER BY [Date];
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the query below.  I omit the `Shortage` and `Surplus` columns.

```
SELECT [Date], Quota, Yield
    , SUM(Yield - Quota) OVER(ORDER BY [Date] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS NetShort
FROM #MyTable
```

Comment: Have you tested that? Pretty sure that doesn't calculate the net shortage correctly. It certainly doesn't match the results returned by the other answer.